# How to properly close a windows application in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows application that when I close it still runs on the background process of task manager. I tried going through Application/Shutdown Mode/When start up form closes, but my startup form is a login form which then takes me to my main application which has a close button. I also tried the option `When last form closes`, no effect.

On this close button I have tried `Me.Close().` and also I have tried `Application.Quit()` my both still not closing my application completely.

How can I terminate the application completely and clear it from the background services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Application.Exit` or `End`...

Comment: `End` is the worst possible way

Comment: You should also bear in mind the differences between `Application.Exit` and `Environment.Exit(0)`.

Comment: @DonA why is end the worst way?

Comment: It shuts down the message pumps immediately and does not allow for the forms to close properly(code you may want to run). There are much better ways to close a form or shut down the app. Idle_Mind's answer is the best, and then `Application.Exit` as a last effort.

Answer (score 1):

"my startup form is a login form which then takes me to my main application"

You are probably hiding the login form with Hide(), which is keeping the app alive.  With the `When last form closes` option set, you can instead call Close() against the login form after showing the main form.  Then it should shut down properly.

Answer (score 0):

In Login form

1. create a instance of `MainForm`
2. show the `MainForm` and close the `Login` form
3. If you want to pass any value to `MainForm` from `Login` form, create a public variable in `MainForm`. Eg.  `Public userAuth As String`

Example:

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
        Dim mf As New MainForm()
        mf.userAuth = "Admin"
        mf.Show()
        Me.Close() 
End Sub
```